# Android design support navigation drawer align on bottom

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, androiddesignsupport

How can I align a part of the items in the navigation drawer (like settings and help) to the bottom of the navigation drawer like the google apps do? Is that supported in the new design support navigation drawer?

Comment: Yes please see this code: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/menu/drawer_view.xml

Comment: @Sree14 this does not align it on the bottom, it just gets aligned below the previous category

Answer (score 0):

Those are ListView's footer views, which are always drawn after every other list item.

```
listView.addFooterView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null));
```

Comment: There is no listview in the design support navigation drawer